# How To Strip HTML Tags From JSON Response In Blackberry

Tags: php, wamp, json, blackberry-jde

I have a php script that returns a JSON response
that i used in android to load a listview.
I now want to achieve the same functionality in blackberry,
but am getting an error when it comes to parsing the JSON response.

The php script excerpt to echo the response is this :

```
                 <?php
                  $response=array();
                   include 'connect.php';
                   $cat=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['category']);
                 ------------
                   array_push($response["items"],$item);
                   echo $json_encode($response);
                   ?>
```

and the response i get on the blackberry simulator is this :

```
      <!DOCTYPE  html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1"/>
       <title>Untitled Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
      </html>
      {"items":[{"id":"1","item_name":"Sparkling Wine"}],"success":1}
```

This response gives an error when trying to parse the JSON response.
I will like a resonse in this format :

```
     {"items":[{"id":"1","item_name":"Sparkling Wine"}],"success":1}
```

without the excess headers. I use exactly the same script on another machine, and it works for android development perfectly. The only difference is that i use XAMPP as my webserver, while on the current machine i use WAMP. I need to know if it is the WAMP server that is muddying up my response. Need help. Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you call the same URL from a regular browser (check the HTML code)? Try returning a dummy JSON string (like `echo $json_encode(array('hello world'))`) and see if this changes anything. I suspect these headers could be added by your server.

Comment: I suspect that too...that is why i added : " I need to know if it is the WAMP server that is muddying up my response" this statement in my question. How can i alter WAMP?

Comment: "I *too* suspect WAMP is the culprit". But please try to open the same page from your browser so that we can rule out the blackberry simulator.

Comment: I opened it....and i am getting valid json in the Browser...can the fault be the blackberry simulator?

Comment: So it seems (maybe it's not a bug but a feature :). But I am afraid I can't help further on this topic.